# Update values in data.table with values from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with around 25 million rows. I am taking a subset of these rows and performing a function which works fine. However, what I then need to do is update the values in original dataset with new values while retaining the rest. I am sure this is straightforward but I just can't get my head around it.

This is a simplified version of what I am dealing with:

```
require("data.table")

df <-data.frame(AREA_CD = c(sample(1:25000000, 25000000, replace=FALSE)), ALLOCATED = 0, ASSIGNED = "A", ID_CD = c(1:25000000))
df$ID_CD <- interaction( "ID", df$ID_CD, sep = "")
dt <- as.data.table(df)

sub_dt <- dt[5:2004,]
sub_dt[,ALLOCATED:=ALLOCATED+1]
sub_dt[,ASSIGNED:="B"]
```

What I am after is the values in 'ALLOCATED' and 'ASSIGNED' from `sub_dt` to replace the 'ALLOCATED' and 'ASSIGNED' values in `dt` based on the 'ID_CD' column. The output I would be after, based on my example, would still have 25 million rows but have 2,000 updated rows. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure to keep your [minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... minimal

Comment: I think something like ```dt[sub_dt, `:=` (ALLOCATED = i.ALLOCATED, ASSIGNED = i.ASSIGNED), on = .(ID_CD)]``` should do. Other than that, I really hope the way you've created the data set wasn't the actual syntax you've used in your real code.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, that works great. And no, the syntax I used in my example is not what I am actually using.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by David Arenburg [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469003/update-values-in-data-table-with-values-from-another-data-table#comment72079323_42469003) explains how to join the subset of modified data back into the original `data.table`.

However, I wonder why the OP doesn't apply the changes directly in the original `data.table` *by reference* using a function which returns a list:

```
my_fun <- function(alloc, assig) {
  list(
    alloc + 1,
    "B")
}
```

With this function the subset of rows can be updated directly within the `data.table`:

```
dt[5:2004, c("ALLOCATED", "ASSIGNED") := my_fun(ALLOCATED, ASSIGNED)]
dt[1:7]
#   AREA_CD ALLOCATED ASSIGNED ID_CD
#1:    1944         0        A   ID1
#2:    3265         0        A   ID2
#3:   15415         0        A   ID3
#4:   14121         0        A   ID4
#5:   10546         1        B   ID5
#6:    2263         1        B   ID6
#7:   12339         1        B   ID7
```

---

#### Benchmark

Due to memory limitations only a smaller data set with 2.5 million rows (instead of 25 million in the OP) is used.

```
library(microbenchmark)
setDT(df)  # coerce df to data.table
microbenchmark(
  copy = dt <- copy(df),
  join = {
    dt <- copy(df)
    sub_dt <- dt[5:2004,]
    sub_dt[,ALLOCATED:=ALLOCATED+1]
    sub_dt[,ASSIGNED:="B"]
    dt[sub_dt, `:=`(ALLOCATED = i.ALLOCATED, ASSIGNED = i.ASSIGNED), on = .(ID_CD)]
  },
  byref = {
    dt <- copy(df)
    dt[5:2004, c("ALLOCATED", "ASSIGNED") := my_fun(ALLOCATED, ASSIGNED)]
  },
  times = 10L
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  copy  13.80400  14.07850  28.22882  14.15836  14.39643 154.70570    10
#  join 239.36476 240.72745 244.27668 243.52967 246.17104 255.06271    10
# byref  14.28806  14.47308  15.00056  14.63147  14.73134  18.71181    10
```

Updating the `data.table` "in place" is much faster than creating a subset and later join. The copy operation is required to start every benchmark run with an unmodified version of `dt`. Therefore, the copy operation is benchmarked as well.

`data.table`version 1.10.4 was used.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hadn't thought of doing something like this. Your suggested route works. However, the issue I have with your solution is that I have set keys in my real version of dt and these are lost once your function is applied.

Comment: Glad, it works. Which fields are keyed? Can you show the result of `data.table::tables()` before and after you apply the function? Perhaps, it's better if you could post a new question with an appropriate [mcve] including the keys?

Comment: I have asked a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491624/matching-unique-and-non-unique-values-between-data-tables-and-update-data-table) relating to this one. Your answer made me think that I have been approaching the larger problem I am trying to solve wrong. I therefore need some help pointing me in the right direction!