# Matching unique and non-unique values between data.tables and update data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have been working on matching values between two large data tables (around 25 million records each) based on unique and non-unique values. I posted a question yesterday [on how to update values in a data.table using another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469003/update-values-in-data-table-with-values-from-another-data-table) and the answers have made me wonder how I can improve the efficiency of this matching. In my example `dt1` contains a non-unique area code and a type which can be from 1 to 10 (along with some blank columns). `dt2` contains the same non-unique area codes (although not the same number as in `dt1`), types from 1 to 10 and a unique ID (`U_ID`).

What I would like to do is find the `AREA_CD` and `TYPE` rows in `dt1` and `dt2` that match and copy the `U_ID` for those rows from `dt2` to `dt1`. The issue is that dt1 and dt2 do not have the same number of instances of each unique combination. For example `AREA_CD` 'A1' and `TYPE` '1' occur 21 times in `dt1` and only 20 times in `dt2`. In these instances then the minimum number of rows (so 20 in this case) would have the match operation applied leaving 1 row in `dt1` unmodified (if `dt2` had more rows than `dt1` then the number of rows in `dt1` would be used).

Here is an example of my dataset. My actual datasets have around 25,000,000 rows and contain around 10,000 unique areas and types from 1 to 10.

```
require("data.table")

df1 <-data.frame(AREA_CD = c(rep("A1", 205), rep("A2", 145), rep("A3", 250), rep("A4", 100), rep("A5", 300)), TYPE = rep(1:10), ALLOCATED = 0, U_ID = 0, ID_CD = c(1:1000))
df1$ID_CD <- interaction( "ID", df1$ID_CD, sep = "")

df2 <-data.frame(U_ID = c(1:1000), AREA_CD = c(rep("A1", 200), rep("A2", 155), rep("A3", 245), rep("A4", 90), rep("A5", 310)), TYPE = rep(1:10), ASSIGNED = 0)
df2$U_ID <- interaction( "U", df2$U_ID, sep = "")

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
```

The output I am looking for would look something like this:

```
for(o in 1:5){
Ao <- paste("A",o,sep="")
for(i in 1:10){
R.Num <- min(nrow(with(df1, df1[AREA_CD == Ao & TYPE == i ,])), nrow(with(df2, df2[AREA_CD == Ao & TYPE == i ,])))
df1[df1$AREA_CD == Ao & df1$TYPE == i,][1:R.Num,"U_ID"]  <- as.character(df2[df2$AREA_CD == Ao & df2$TYPE == i,][1:R.Num,"U_ID"])
}}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each group of `AREA_CD` and `TYPE`, the OP wants to match the rows one to one in the order they appear in both data.tables. E.g., the first row with `AREA_CD == "A1" & TYPE == 1` in `dt1` shall match the first row with `AREA_CD == "A1" & TYPE == 1` in `dt2`, then the second rows and so forth.

This can be done in a join operation if a row index `I` (or running count) within each group is added:

```
# add row indices
dt1[, I := seq_len(.N), by = .(AREA_CD, TYPE)]
dt2[, I := seq_len(.N), by = .(AREA_CD, TYPE)]

# alternative code: same result as above but more concise
dt1[, I := rowid(AREA_CD, TYPE)]
dt2[, I := rowid(AREA_CD, TYPE)]


# right join (all rows of dt1 are used)
dt0 <- dt2[dt1, on = .(AREA_CD, TYPE, I)]

# show result for one group
dt0[AREA_CD == "A1" & TYPE == 1, ]
#    U_ID AREA_CD TYPE ASSIGNED  I ALLOCATED i.U_ID ID_CD
# 1:   U1      A1    1        0  1         0      0   ID1
# 2:  U11      A1    1        0  2         0      0  ID11
# 3:  U21      A1    1        0  3         0      0  ID21
#...
#19: U181      A1    1        0 19         0      0 ID181
#20: U191      A1    1        0 20         0      0 ID191
#21:   NA      A1    1       NA 21         0      0 ID201
```

Note that the last row has a `NA` in some columns. This is due to the different number of rows for this group in `dt1` and `dt2`. `dt1` has 21 rows while `dt2` has only 20 rows. So, the last row of `dt1` has no match in `dt2`.

Alternatively, a inner join will only return rows with a match in both `dt1` and `dt2`:

```
# inner join
dt0 <- dt2[dt1, on = .(AREA_CD, TYPE, I), nomatch = 0]

# show result for one group
dt0[AREA_CD == "A1" & TYPE == 1, ]
#    U_ID AREA_CD TYPE ASSIGNED  I ALLOCATED i.U_ID ID_CD
# 1:   U1      A1    1        0  1         0      0   ID1
# 2:  U11      A1    1        0  2         0      0  ID11
# 3:  U21      A1    1        0  3         0      0  ID21
#...
#18: U171      A1    1        0 18         0      0 ID171
#19: U181      A1    1        0 19         0      0 ID181
#20: U191      A1    1        0 20         0      0 ID191
```

Now, only 20 rows are returned for this group.

---

#### Data

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  AREA_CD = factor(c(rep("A1", 205), rep("A2", 145), rep("A3", 250), rep("A4", 100), rep("A5", 300))), 
  TYPE = rep(1:10), 
  ALLOCATED = 0, 
  U_ID = 0, 
  ID_CD = factor(paste0("ID", 1:1000)))
dt2 <- data.table(
  U_ID = factor(paste0("U", 1:1000)), 
  AREA_CD = factor(c(rep("A1", 200), rep("A2", 155), rep("A3", 245), rep("A4", 90), rep("A5", 310))), 
  TYPE = rep(1:10), 
  ASSIGNED = 0)
```

Note that `ID_CD` and `U_ID` are created using `paste0()` instead of `interaction()` which turned out to be rather slow.

Comment: `I := seq_len(.N), by = .(AREA_CD, TYPE)` should be the same as `I := rowid(AREA_CD, TYPE)`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank Yes, your right. `?rowid` says that it _is intended for interactive use_. So, I decided to stay with `.N` and `by =`. Perhaps, the code would look a bit smarter using the `rowid()`? Edited in.

Comment: @UweBlock Thanks for your answer. It works great and does exactly what I need it to do.